# Multiple Stroke in gesture does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gesture

I have tried to implement Multiple Strokes in gesture but it does not work.

My question is, I want to draw multiple stroke using gesture but when I finish drawing one stroke and try to draw another the previous one disappears. I set the following settings but they don't work.

```
android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
android:fadeEnabled="false"
```

This is my XML file

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/SeeAndDrawGesture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    android:uncertainGestureColor="#FF4040" >
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Comment: android:gestureStrokeType="multiple" should let you draw multiple strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using:

```
android:fadeOffset="in miliseconds"
```

works for me